# Autolayout Dumbness (Mine)?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm using auto layout in one of my projects and am having trouble with what I thought should be a trivial task.

As an example, I have two text boxes below each other. I have created a vertical spacing constraint between the two, of 5 points.

I would expect that if i move the top text box (using setFrame), the constraint would mean that the bottom one would automatically move with it to enforce the constraint?

Is my thinking correct? or am I using auto layout in a way that it was not meant to. ie. I have misunderstood its purpose. Or should I be moving the top text box using a different manner other than setFrame?

Any input would be great. Thanks in advance :-)

PS. I have played around with using: setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints which seems to work. However, this doesn't seem like the proper way to do this. My initial thoughts are that auto layout is supposed to handle size/position relationships with little code, in this case, i would expect it would be handled with zero code.

Comment: I am kind of an iOS newb, but I don't think autolayout respects relationships that *change* over time.  I think it is a one-time thing (initial layout).  So yeah, it does kinda sound like you are hacking at it.  Could be wrong, though...

Comment: @BrendanHannemann Yes, it does respect relationships that change over time. Anytime you call 'setNeedsLayout', it will recalculate where the positions should be.

Comment: But, mixing user specified layout (setFrame:) and auto-layout is a recipe for disaster. Either use user specified layout for both (override layoutSubviews and calculate the position of both boxes), or user auto-layout for both, also for your top text box.

Comment: @fishinear ah ok, good to know.  But also maybe the guy also needs to call that method (`setNeedsLayout`)?

Comment: @BrendanHannemann setNeedsLayout is called automatically in all cases where iOS can see that something has changed (such as change of size of the superview). You usually only need to call setNeedsLayout yourself when you are doing manual layout, and you want to explicitly move/resize a view.

Comment: setNeedsLayout doesn't seem to work here. From the comments, it seems that changing the frame directly isn't best practice when using auto layout, i guess you are right in that i should not be mixing manual layout with auto layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use setFrame to do that. Auto-layout decides the frame. If you change it after the fact the constraints aren't automatically updated.

You could get a reference to the constraint that decides the Y position (either when you create it programmatically or using an IBOutlet) of the top box and change its value. That would trigger an update to recompute the position of everything and run layout again.

You would do that by changing the value of the constant property on the NSLayoutConstraint object.

[Reference Docs Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html)

Comment: My problem with using and manipulating constraints for this is that i want the controls below the first control to move in relation to the height of the first text box. The text boxes were just an example, I really have a collection view control with controls below it. As the content of the collectionview changes, so does its height so all items are viewable always. I want the controls below the collection view to move down in relation to the height of the collection view. Not sure if i can do this by referencing a constraint - since i'm not sure what value to assign to the constraint?

Comment: If you want to programmatically control the height of the collection view just set a height constraint on the control and change the constant property of that constraint to the value you calculate. However, it sounds like you are trying to put a footer onto a collection view. That's a different scenario as you are really trying to place something below the last cell rather than below the view itself. Is that true?

Comment: No, not a footer. Just a bunch a few other controls that need to appear below the collection. Your comments have given me a clue though, as recommended, I'll try creating a height constraint for the collection and changing it at run-time. I'm guessing auto layout will be used more effectively this way rather than using the 'setTranslates....' Method I mentioned above.